# External links into specific Angular 2.0 SPA states don't work

Tags: html, angular, iis, url-rewriting, angular2-routing

I'm using AngularJS 2.4.6, Typescript 2.1.2, IIS 8.0, Chrome, Visual Studio 2015

I was working with the Angular Heroes tutorial and noticed that when I refreshed the browser I got a 404 response (due the PathLocationStrategy -aka HTML5 pathing - used by default)...  So that made sense because IIS sees no /dashboard to return.

There are plenty of solutions out there using URL rewriting, which I did and that does indeed route to the index.html correctly.

My problem is, when I refresh the browser I'd like it to be on the same state it was on.  This worked fine with angular 1.5 using the hash strategy like it does.

Do I need to do something specific to create this behavior?  As is (Angular 2.0), the refresh ends up causing the base state to show up and not the one I was on.

I notice that the Rewrite action sends a 301 back to the browser, so again the index.html has no knowledge of the intended state.

Importantly, how would an external link (eg. from an email) into an Angular 2 app specific state work?

For example, if I send out an email with a link to my app like:
  https://myserver/some/path/to/aState

This simple scenario doesn't seem to work with IIS from everything I've tried.

This project does not involve MVC.  The client code makes ajax requests to a webapi middletier web, but for the purposes of what I'm asking, you can assume there are no http calls at all.

Comment: That just works in Angular2 (`HashLocationStrategy` and `PathLocationStrategy`) Hard to tell what's wrong in your application without seeing any code. Are you serving the app at the root path or a sub-directory?

Comment: I'm not sure what to show as code in this case.  As far as I can tell a link like in my OP will get a 404.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you develop your solution using `ASP.NET MVC` on **Visual Studio 2015**, and index.html at the root directory of your solution, with a minimum of file/folder structure as follows:

```
- /Controllers
- index.html
- /src/app/ (Angular source)
- web.config
```

**Step 1**: web.config configuration

Add the following `rewrite rules` to `system.webServer` section of your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="clientRewrite rule" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/api/" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />      
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/assets/" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

This configuration will redirect all requests (except /api, and /assets) to your index.html. You can customize this behavior.

Also, don't forget to enable `webpages` in `appSettings`:

```
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
```

#### **EDIT**

Add `buildProviders` for `html` extension in `system.web``compilation` section.

```
<buildProviders>
  <add extension=".html" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider, System.Web.WebPages.Razor" />
</buildProviders>
```

**Step 2**: index.html

Make sure you include `base href`, located between `<head> ... </head>` tags on your index.html:

```
<base href="/">
```

**Step 3**: Global.asax configuration

You will need to register `html` extension. Simply add the following method to Global.asax.cs:

```
public static void RegisterHtmlExtension()
{
    RazorCodeLanguage.Languages.Add("html", new CSharpRazorCodeLanguage());
    WebPageHttpHandler.RegisterExtension("html");
}
```

and call `RegisterHtmlExtension();` in the `Application_Start()` method.

You won't need to register routes for your `angular views` (templates). The following (minimal) server route config would be enough:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("favicon.ico");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    //register custom routes (extensions, etc)
    var routePublisher = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IRoutePublisher>();
    routePublisher.RegisterRoutes(routes);
}
```

If you have WebAPI controllers, you might need the appropriate route configuration for them. This configuration should work:

```
public static class WebApiRouteProvider
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "DefaultApi",
            "api/{controller}/{id}",
            new { area = "api", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

And, you must register these routes by calling `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiRouteProvider.Register);` in in the `Application_Start()` method.

**Conclusion**

This way, you'll be able to redirect all requests to your index.html (except paths explicitly defined at the rewrite rules).

And, Angular will be able to intercept all requests with given paths (ex: http://yoursite.com/about/us, http://yoursite.com/account/login, etc) which will result rendered components with the given routes.

Comment: I am hitting a webapi middle tier via angular's http module, so similar to mvc on the backside (but of course no Controller folder in my visual studio project in this case, just transpiled js and html - the middle tier is it's own web using C#/webapi).  Sorry for the delay, I'm reviewing the rest of your answer.

Comment: Really, MVC is not a consideration in this case.  If someone follows a link like http://example.com/apath/dashboard it would show a 404.  If I go to the app via http://example.com all is good, I can then route to say dashboard via the router, but if I hit refresh I get 404.

Comment: I'm assuming I want any request for an html, css, image file that exists to return the item.  Any request that is a valid router path to resolve correctly and any path that is not a valid router path to default/route to my login component.  IIS will see both a valid and invalid router path as a 404 situation.

Comment: If you say that you can navigate the app via example.com, it means that your default document is INDEX.HTML, and is properly resolved. Meantime, I edited the answer, by adding `buildProviders` section in your `web.config.`

Comment: Just want to make sure, did you include `<base href="/">` or `<base href="/index.html">` between `<head> ... </head>` tags?

Comment: Yeah, we have <base href="/"> and we aren't using MVC.   A routerlink in a navbar works fine <a routerLink="/Login">Login</a>, but reloading once on say Login, or just pasting that path into the url gives a 404.

Comment: I may appear to be repeating same topics, in order to realize steps to reproduce. So, you're not using MVC as far as i understood and just depend on IIS Express (which's the dev server). And did you use the rewrite rules with the  other stuff on web.config; and changes to Global.asax - that i mentioned?

Comment: If I have an angular route like example.com/mysite/exists and someone goes to example/mysite/notexists then I assume I'd have to make rewrite entries to cover every valid Angular route I have defined?

Comment: @Brandon, I was expecting an answer to the question above to help you better. Well, I'll suggest you another method: Try to build a solution from scratch in VS2015, create just two `Angular` modules (AppModule, and AboutModule`. You can use any starter project for Angular app (ex: https://github.com/angular/quickstart, https://github.com/nglibs/example-app) and follow the steps above. It should run without a problem. Then, compare with your project settings - it will be easier to identify where it fails.

Comment: Thanks, as soon as time permits I'll dig in more with what you have given input on so far and let you know the results!

Comment: You're welcome, and don't hesitate to ask if you need further help. Happy MVC'ing ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the hash strategy?

```
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true })
```

Comment: Google recommends the path strategy I believe.  We used hash for Angular 1.x, but we'd like to move to using the path strategy.

Comment: It's still worth trying for debugging purposes. If it works, it's a server side issue with HTML5 pushState.

Comment: I would expect hash strategy to work in this case.  But what about a static link that is the router path?  IIS basically has no idea it's a valid router path and responds 404 right?  I just figured it would be fairly straight forward, but maybe not?

Comment: It just needs to return `index.html` for unknown URLs.

Comment: IIS would do that for images, css, tec I assume, and a valid router path would still cause IIS to return index.html, but not actually go to the correct state right?